# Scala - choose constructor by runtime type of constructor arguments

Tags: scala

I have a class with several different constructors, which differ in the types of parameters, when all these parameters extend from the same base class.

See here for a simplified example:

```
abstract case class GeneralDataType()
case class SpecificDataTypeOne() extends GeneralDataType
case class SpecificDataTypeTwo() extends GeneralDataType

case class MyNumber(myDataType: Int) extends {
  def this(data: SpecificDataTypeOne) = this(1)
  def this(data: SpecificDataTypeTwo) = this(2)
}

def getDataType(typeId: Int): GeneralDataType = typeId match {
  case 1 => new SpecificDataTypeOne
  case 2 => new SpecificDataTypeTwo
}

val x = getDataType(1)

// error: Cannot resolve constructor
val mn = new MyNumber(x)
```

How in runtime to choose the correct constructor to use, according to the parameter types?

Comment: in eclipse I'm getting this error: case class SpecificDataTypeOne has case ancestor GeneralDataType, but case-to-case inheritance is prohibited. To overcome this limitation, use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other suggested, try to use companion object as factory(I still has error that I've added to comment, but might be it's scala version dependent?)

```
object MyNumber {
  def apply(x:GeneralDataType) : MyNumber = x match {
      case SpecificDataTypeOne() => new MyNumber(1)
      case SpecificDataTypeTwo() => new MyNumber(2)
  }

  def getDataType(typeId: Int): GeneralDataType = typeId match {
      case 1 => new SpecificDataTypeOne
      case 2 => new SpecificDataTypeTwo
    }
    val x = getDataType(1)
    val mn = MyNumber(x)
}
case class MyNumber(myDataType: Int)


abstract case class GeneralDataType()
  case class SpecificDataTypeOne() extends GeneralDataType
  case class SpecificDataTypeTwo() extends GeneralDataType
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure you use case. While companion object can be used in the case.

```
object MyNumber {
  def apply(typeId: Int): MyNumber = typeId match {
    case 1 => new MyNumber(new SpecificDataTypeOne)
    case 2 => new MyNumber(new SpecificDataTypeTwo)
  }
}

val mn = MyNumber(1)
```

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood the question.
I get an object of either types (SpecificDataTypeOne or Two) from outside, and then want to call the appropriate constructor based on it's type.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do it for one `GeneralDataType` (or maybe a few) and a few constructors each, pattern matching will do what you need:

```
x match {
  case y1: SpecificDataTypeOne => new MyNumber(y1)
  case y2: SpecificDataTypeTwo => new MyNumber(y2)
}
```

You can make a more general solution using reflection, but it should only be used if the above is not good enough.

Comment: if I try to overload MyNumber's constructor to contain your code, it doesn't work...

Comment: You mean something like `def this(data: GeneralDataType) = data match ...`? No, it won't. Use an `apply` method in the companion object instead, as in Rockie Yang's answer (just take `GeneralDataType` as argument).